# Javascript : shortcut to access object sub properties if defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shortcut

As a programmer, I love shortcuts, and I'm very curious. So I was wondering, is there any way to do this shorter ?

```
const {params} = props.route;
const transactionId =
  params && params.transactionId ? params.transactionId : null;
```

Basically, I am looking for a way to access props.route.params.transactionId if and only if props.route.params is defined, so I can get the (potential) value of transactionId without raising an exception if props.route.params is undefined.

Comment: `params?.transactionId || null`

Comment: Awesome, thanks, and sorry I couldn't find the answer (wrong keywrods)